# Composing Java Bifunction and Function

Tags: java

How can I compose a Bifunction with a function in the folowing example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    BiFunction<String, Integer, String> zeroPadding = (string, zeros) -> String.format("%0" +zeros+ "d", Integer.valueOf(string));

    Function<String, String> removeNonDigitChars = (string) -> string.replaceAll("\\D", "");
}
```

First I want to remove non digits chars, and the removeNonDigitChars result pass to zeroPadding BiFunction with parameters.

I've tried:

```
zeroPadding.andThen(removeNonDigitChars).apply("789.65", 8);
```

and

```
removeNonDigitChars.compose(zeroPadding).apply("789.65", 8);
```

But none of two works.

Comment: `zeroPadding.apply(removeNonDigitChars.apply("789.65"), 8);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your two attempts are applying the functions in the wrong order. You want `removeNonDigitChars` applied to the string *before* giving the string to `zeroPadding`.

Unfortunately, you can't use `andThen()` or `compose()` to combined the two functions.

If you want a combined function, just combine them yourself:

```
BiFunction<String, Integer, String> combined = (string, zeros) ->
        zeroPadding.apply(removeNonDigitChars.apply(string), zeros);
```

Then use like this:

```
combined.apply("789.65", 8) // returns "00078965"
```

Comment: I understood. Thank you.